# Development Mode Service Worker Script is Different after Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I have a ReactJS web with two modes: **development** and **production**.

- development mode using port: 3001
- production using port: 3000

Service worker in development mode is running normally. But, after I run the build process. the result of the output script differs from the development mode.

**How to make the service worker script output the same (development mode and production)?**

***service-worker.js*** (*development mode output script*)

```
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = 'v-208';
// const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.html';
const OFFLINE_URL = [    
  '/offline.html', 
  '/media/error/bg6.jpg',
  '/favicon.ico'
];

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(async function() {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    await cache.addAll(OFFLINE_URL);
  }());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  
  var cacheWhitelist = [CACHE_NAME];
   
  event.waitUntil(async function() {
    
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })

    // Feature-detect
    if (self.registration.navigationPreload) {
      // Enable navigation preloads!
      await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
    }
  }());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const { request } = event;

  // Always bypass for range requests, due to browser bugs
  if (request.headers.has('range')) return;
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    // Try to get from the cache:
    const cachedResponse = await caches.match(request);
    if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse;

    try {
      // See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload#using_the_preloaded_response
      const response = await event.preloadResponse;
      if (response) return response;

      // Otherwise, get from the network
      return await fetch(request);
    } catch (err) {
      // If this was a navigation, show the offline page:
      if (request.mode === 'navigate') {
        return caches.match('offline.html');
      }

      // Otherwise throw
      throw err;
    }
  }());
});
```

**build process** :

```
npm run build
```

**then I run it using pm2** :

```
pm2 serve build --watch --name ekinerja-frontend 3000 --spa
```

***service-worker.js*** (*production mode output script*)

```
importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.4cd8995656b1c33c355715652d9d2264.js"
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.core.clientsClaim();

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL("/index.html"), {
  
  blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^/?]+\.[^/]+$/],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the path of registering for service worker. After build the whole code will move to a new folder. So it will be suggested that keep your service worker outside src, in the static folder and use this while registering your SW-
`if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) { navigator.serviceWorker .register("/static/js/serviceWorker.js") .then(....)}`